# How to add product into cart using $broadcast and $on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  var count = 0;
  var found = false;
  $scope.addProduct = function (prodDetails) {
        angular.forEach($scope.cartProducts, function (newProduct, index) {

            var a = angular.equals(newProduct, prodDetails);
            found = true;
        });

        if (found) {
            prodDetails['qty']++;
        } else {
            prodDetails['qty'] = 0;
            $scope.cartProducts.push(prodDetails);
            count++;
        }

        console.log($scope.cartProducts);

        //  count++;

        $rootScope.$broadcast('addProduct-ToCart', $scope.cartProducts);
        console.log('check');

    }
```

// cartController

```
   $scope.cartItems = [];
   cartFactory.cartProducts().then(function (response) {

        $scope.cartItems = response.data;
      //  console.log(response.data);
        console.log($scope.cartItems);

      }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });

    $rootScope.$on('addProduct-ToCart', function (event, data) {
      console.log('check');
    });
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: I tried formatting the code as much as I could but there's not enough context here. Describe the problem in details. First thing I notice is you set found = true in a loop? It's a weird way to tell someone added a product. Then var a is never used.

Comment: I want to add  this product and display it in the cart but I am not able to do it. Also when I'am trying to add multiple products its getting refresh

Comment: I know this question is not formatted properly but please help me out with this

Comment: Please follow the link @31piy added here. You've only posted a couple of snippets, so the best we can do is assume here.

Comment: still looking for an answer? check this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/am6IDw?p=preview